# How to select all curves on or outside a region?

Tags: functions, function-construction

How would you select all curves that are on boundary of the region or outside the boundary of the region(including lines with points on the boundary)?

```
points = {{4, 5.`}, {5.`, 5.`}, {5.`, 0.`}, {-5.`, 0.`}, {-5.`, 
    5.`}, {-2.`, 5.`}, {-2, 1.`}, {2, 1.`}, {2, 5}, {4, 5.`}};
region = ListLinePlot[points, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 8}}, 
   GridLines -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]];
functions = {ConditionalExpression[Abs[1 - 2 x], x >= 1 || x <= 0], 
   ConditionalExpression[1, -1 <= x <= 0], 
   ConditionalExpression[1 - x, 0 <= x <= 1/2], 
   ConditionalExpression[5 + x, -2 <= x <= 1], 
   ConditionalExpression[5 - x, 3 <= x <= 4], 
   ConditionalExpression[6 + x, -1.5 <= x <= 3]};
Show[{g, Plot[functions, {x, -5, 5}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: is the desired result all solid lines except the magenta line?

Comment: @kglr result is all lines except three lines inside the region on the right. I'm not at the PC now so I cannot indicate it on the image.

Comment: @kglr I'm sorry that the first function has two branches but part of one branch is inside the region so it's not picked. So there are 3 functions to be removed with one on the boundary and the other two outside the region.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
polygon = Polygon@points; 

lines = Cases[Plot[functions, {x, -5, 5}], 
   {_Directive, l__Line} :> Line[{l}[[All, 1]]], All];


f = Or[RegionWithin[RegionBoundary[polygon], #], 
     RegionIntersection[polygon, #] === EmptyRegion[2]] &;

f /@ lines
```

> ```
>  {False, True, False, True, False, True}
> ```

```
selected = Select[f]@lines;

Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Red, Dashed}], White, polygon,
   Dashing[{}], Thick, MapIndexed[{ColorData[97] @ #2[[1]], #} &] @ selected}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is nice too.

Comment: I got error with  `Multicells -> True` as the function only accept two agruments.

Comment: The code works without error/warning messages in version 11.3.0 (windows) and 13.0 (wolfram cloud).

Comment: my version is 12.2.0.0 (windows). I'll check it

Comment: This is the error I got. 
https://ibb.co/3z7zCby

Comment: looks like a version 12 issue (fixed in v 13.0)

Comment: Would there an alternative to replace that part? I could update but I don't want to close all the work I'm doing now.

Comment: hana, try the updated version.

Comment: I wonder if you deleted `If` function in `Case` on purpose? 
`Cases[Plot[functions[[1]], {x, -5, 5}][[1]], {_Directive, l__Line} :>
     If[Length@{l} == 1, l, Line[{l}[[All, 1]]]], All][[1]]`

Comment: I changed it to `Cases[Plot[functions, {x, -5, 5}][[1]], {_Directive, l__Line} :> 
   If[Length@{l} == 1, First@{l}, Line[{l}[[All, 1]]]], All][[1]]` but then the `f` function causes error as the first function has two branches.

`RegionWithin::reg: {{{-5.,11.},{-4.99693,10.9939},{-4.99387,10.9877},{-4.98773,10.9755},{-4.97546,10.9509},{-4.95093,10.9019},{-4.90186,10.8037},{-4.80371,10.6074},{-4.59092,10.1818},{-4.39222,9.78444},<<49>>},{<<1>>}} is not a correctly specified region.`

Comment: Ah I made some mistake `lines = Cases[
  Plot[functions, {x, -5, 5}][[1]], {_Directive, l__Line} :> 
   If[Length@{l} == 1, First@{l}, Line[{l}[[All, 1]]]], All]` Thanks.

Comment: re _"I wonder ..."_, the current version is shorter and more general (`If[...]` was not needed).

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

```
reg = Polygon[points];
curves = DiscretizeRegion /@ (ParametricRegion[{x, #}, {{x, -5, 
         5}}] & /@ functions);
RegionDisjoint[#, reg] & /@ curves
```

> `{False, False, False, True, False, True}`

**Original**

```
dist = RegionDistance[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[region]]
Show[region, 
 Plot[functions, {x, -5, 5}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, dist[{x, y}] > 0]]]
```

[image]

Comment: I think I didn't explain it clear enough. I want to select all lines/functions where it locate on the boundary or outside the boundary region.

Comment: Thanks, the new one works.

Comment: I did think to pick some points on the curves then check if they are inside the region but didn't know DiscretizeRegion like that.

Comment: I forgot to add that the second one should be `True` as it is on the boundary.