# How to keep lines on boundary or inside a region?

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, function-construction, regions

This post is related to one of my [previous](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265599/how-to-select-all-curves-on-or-outside-a-region/265600#comment700824_265600) posts. My goal is to keep only the lines that fall on the boundary `(2, 8)` or inside the region `(3, 5)`, or that intersect with the polygon region `(1)`.
Please note that lines such as `line 7` should be removed.

The code below works for this purpose and the result is what I want, but I'm concerned about its accuracy. When I check `RegionIntersection[polygon, #]` with `line 4`, it returns an empty region, which is what I want, but it doesn't seem logical to me, as the line and the polygon intersect at one point. Upon further investigation, I found that the point `(-2,3)` is represented as `{-1.999996701, 3.000003299}` by the `line 4`, which explains why there is no intersection.

Does anyone know of a method to ensure that there are no errors related to floating-point numbers or other issues? Also, in my actual case, I have around 4000 functions, so plotting all of them would be slow.

[image]

```
points = {{4, 5.`}, {5.`, 5.`}, {5.`, 0.`}, {-5.`, 0.`}, {-5.`, 
    5.`}, {-2.`, 5.`}, {-2, 1.`}, {2, 1.`}, {2, 5}, {4, 5.`}};
region = ListLinePlot[points, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 8}}, 
   GridLines -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]];
functions = {ConditionalExpression[2 x - 1, x >= 1], 
   ConditionalExpression[5, -4 <= x <= -1.5], 
   ConditionalExpression[1 - x, 0 <= x <= 1/2], 
   ConditionalExpression[5 + x, -2 <= x <= 1], 
   ConditionalExpression[5 - x, 3 <= x <= 4], 
   ConditionalExpression[6 + x, -1.5 <= x <= 3], 
   ConditionalExpression[2, -2 <= x <= 2],
   ConditionalExpression[1, -2 <= x <= -1]};
Show[{region, 
  Plot[functions, {x, -5, 5}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]}]

polygon = Polygon@points;
lines = Cases[
   Plot[functions, {x, -5, 5}], {_Directive, l__Line} :> 
    Line[{l}[[All, 1]]], All];
f = RegionIntersection[polygon, #] === EmptyRegion[2] &;
f /@ lines
(* {False, False, False, True, False, True, True, False} *)
```

I didn't use the cvgmt code in my previous post because I was concerned about its accuracy. DiscretizeRegion only samples some points, which can lead to potential inaccuracies.

Comment: What is your exact definition of overlap? Is it that region intersection should have `RegionDimension`of at least 1?

Comment: @kirma that is a new concept to me but `RegionDimension` of dimension 1 seems to be exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(* Rationalise points, convert polygon to an implicit region form. *)
polygon = RegionConvert[Polygon@Rationalize@points, "Implicit"];

(* Convert functions to implicit region form with
   inexact values rationalised. *)
lines = functions /. 
   ConditionalExpression[yval_, dom_] :> 
    ImplicitRegion[Rationalize[y == yval && dom], {x, y}];

(* Find those lines whose intersection with polygon is not empty and
   doesn't consist only of detached point(s). *)
RegionDimension[RegionIntersection[polygon, #]] >= 1 & /@ lines

(* {True, True, True, False, True, False, False, True} *)
```

There are couple of things of relevance on this code:

- Avoid inexact numbers. They will cause even more pain than you have observed with region intersections.
- Apparently there's yet another bug with `Polygon`s when handing regions. Thankfully converting the polygon to implicit form works around it.

---

**EDIT**:

If you don't have `RegionConvert` in your version of Mathematica, you can substitute it in this case with the following:

```
ClearAll[RegionConvert];

RegionConvert[reg_, "Implicit"] :=
 Module[{x},
  With[
   {vars = Array[x, RegionEmbeddingDimension[reg]]},
   ImplicitRegion[
    Refine[RegionMember[reg, vars],
     Element[Alternatives @@ vars, Reals]],
    vars]]]
```

Comment: That looks nice. I'll check it a bit later as I'm using old version now which does not have RegionConvert.

Comment: @hana I added a workaround for missing `RegionConvert` which I tested on v12.2.

Comment: Since [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/281777/the-region-and-polygon-dont-match-is-it-a-bug/281784?noredirect=1#281777) appears to be a bug, I was wondering if you know of any possible workarounds?